# What is the best way to map data of junction table in Java entity?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have three tables which presents my very simple project.

```
CREATE TABLE company (
  id   INT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE employee (
  id   INT          NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE company_employee (
  company_id  INT NOT NULL,
  employee_id INT NOT NULL,
  hire_date   DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  resign_date DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (company_id) REFERENCES company (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee (id)
);
```

And I have Java representation

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "employees")
    private List<Company> companies;


@Entity
@Table(name = "company")
public class Company implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "company_employee",
               joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")})
    private Collection<Employee> employees;
```

I can't figured out where I can store history data. In history data I need to store hire_date, resign_date of emplyee and to store all companies of each emplyee as well. So my question is haw can I manage such infortation and what is the best way to store all that history info?

Answer (score 1):

That is a many to many relationship with attributes. I am sure you will be able to understand who to deal with it with one basic example:

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-example-join-table-extra-column-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

You have already an intersection table "company_employee".

You can store here employee1 1.1.2013 to 31.12.2013 @ company1. And an other time 1.1.2014 ... 31.12.2014 @ company2.

You have to order by hire_date desc. Per defenition the first value in the list is the current or last employment and all other are consindert as history.

It's not a matter of where to store but how to read the data.

Comment: Maybe it's better to store whole info about employee history in the Company entity?

Comment: I would not agree. Since this data does relate to the employee. You just have to map the company_employee relation accordingly

Comment: Ok. So how can I retrieve `hire_date` and `resign_date` for example for all employees in the system?

Comment: I mean from Hibernate.